# SQL query containing text will not return result if text field is empty

Tags: sql

Was wondering if someone can help me with a SAP SQL query that I have that will not return result if text field is empty. I need T1.LineText to return all results whether empty or not.

```
SELECT 
    T0.TaxDate, T0.NumAtCard, T1.LineText, T0.TrackNo, 
    T0.U_TrackRT1 
FROM 
    ODLN T0 
INNER JOIN 
    DLN10 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
WHERE  
    T0.TaxDate =[%0] AND T0.Cardcode =[%1]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: If needed all records from DLN10 T1, then use it as a main table and use LEFT OUTER JOIN.